# Is it still possible to download all photos from Google Photos, and if so how?

Tags: google-photos

A bunch of my photos ended up getting corrupted on my SD card, and I would like to download my photos from google photos to replace them. However, I'm not sure whether this is still possible. I found this on Google's help page:

https://support.google.com/photos/answer/7652919?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

Which further lead to this:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190

This link stated that

> You can export and download your data from the Google products you
> use, such as your:
>
> [...]
>
> Photos

Which made me think it would be possible

The page further lead here:

https://takeout.google.com/

However, following the directions laid out in the help pages simply does not work to download my photos. Instead of a large download of image files, the download consisted of less than 1MB of what appeared to be metadata. I checked my email to see if the link they said they'd send me lead to my actual data download. It lead to a page to download the same thing I already downloaded

I looked at other times this question has been asked on web applications. Apparently this method used to work. It doesn't seem to work anymore, or maybe the process has changed since then

I feel like I'm missing a step here. But I've done everything according to what google said to do. Has anyone successfully downloaded data from google takeout recently? Is there another way if Google *has* removed this feature? Could it be a glitch?

Answer (score 0):

Organize the photos you want into an album.
From the three dot menu, select "Download all".
You'll get a zip file with all the files with their
original names, and original metadata including location if it was added by the original camera.

[image]

However any "description", comments or likes will not be present in the downloaded file.

The resolution of the image may be lower than your original, based on your storage saver settings.